# use of ajax with django for passing information

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, python-2.7

I am trying to test the use of ajax with django views. I am new to ajax and django. I have created a grid of 3*3 cells of buttons. When I click any button, it replaces its text with and 'X' and then should be passed to view "handler" with the help of ajax. But it is not passing the control to view "handler" in my case. I don't understand why it is not working.
Here is my code:

url file:

```
 from django.conf.urls import include, url
    from django.contrib import admin
    from game import views
    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
        url(r'^handler/',views.handler,name='handler'),
        url(r'^$',views.home,name='home'),
    ]
```

views file

```
from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    from django.http import Http404

    def handler(request):
        if request.is_ajax():
            pos = request.POST['pos']
            return HttpResponse(2)
        else:
            raise Http404
    def home(request):
        context = {}
        return render(request,"game/home.html",context)
```

home.html file:

```
<head>
<head>
<style>
td {
    padding:0;
}
table {
    height:240px;
    width:240px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0
}
input {
    margin:0;
    width:80px;
    height:80px;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
#content {
    position:absolute;
    top:210px;
    left:540px;
}
</style>
<script>
function change(id)
{
    var y = document.getElementById(id);
    y.value = 'X';
    $.ajax({
        url:"handler/",
        type:"POST",
        data:{pos:id},

        success:function(data) {
            var x = document.getElementById(data);
            x.value = 'O';
            console.log("sucess");
        },
        error:function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id = "content">
<center><table>
<tr>
<td><input type = "button" onclick="change(1)" id = "1"></input></td>
<td><input type = "button" onclick="change(2)" id = "2"></input></td>
<td><input type = "button" onclick="change(3)" id = "3"></input></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type = "button" onclick="change(4)" id = "4"></input></td>
<td><input type = "button" onclick="change(5)" id = "5"></input></td>
<td><input type = "button" onclick="change(6)" id = "6"></input></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type = "button" onclick="change(7)" id = "7"></input></td>
<td><input type = "button" onclick="change(8)" id = "8"></input></td>
<td><input type = "button" onclick="change(9)" id = "9"></input></td>
</tr>
</table>
</center>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add `print 'Checkpoint'` and `print pos` under `pos = request.POST['pos']` and let me know if anything is printed in the console when you activate the AJAX request. Also, is the `success` or `error` functions returning the `console.log('success')` or `alert("error")`?

Comment: In fact, control is even not passing to "handler" view inside which you asked to print.

Comment: There are many things that could go wrong. One of them I can see is that you didn't handle `csrf` token, which might give you 403 response. You should open up the console of your browser and see if it's the case. If so, your view.py method might not even get called. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/csrf/

Comment: @ShangWang Is probably right, try changing `data:{pos:id},` to `data:{pos: id, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},` - You will need that even if it isn't the main problem. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: I changed but the problem remains the same

Comment: Does the console in your browser say anything? Do you get any http response?

Comment: No.The control is not passed to the view that handles ajax request

Comment: I think Shawn is talking about the console in the browser, so you can debug the java script itself. Are you getting the 'error' alert? Add a console.log(err) to see any errors sent by the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use csrf_exempt decorator since you don't send csrf token it via ajax. In addition make sure you have included `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`into your template file. That should work.

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.http import Http404

@csrf_exempt
def handler(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        pos = request.POST['pos']
        return HttpResponse(2)
    else:
        raise Http404
```